# I am getting exception for the Status bar appearance in exception breakpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uistatusbar, xcode7.2

I have made the View controller based status bar ... YES since i am managing my status bar.

But some of my code still have the code Setstatusbarhidden:YES/NO old style deprecated API calls.

Is there any leads or advice what may be wrong in this case.

[image: Attaching the screenshot for teh exception breakpoint stack trace.]

Comment: You will get (better) answers if you include the exception.

Comment: The app just stops at main file and I can continue this exception but wanted to find out why app stuck at this exception on app launch. Also this don't terminate if I remove the exception breakpoint added.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: There is no exception , I apologise as i cant give you as i don't see anything at start in console log just the exception breakpoint stops. The image that i sent above. if I do in console 'po $arg1' maximum this log i get . error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't read the value of register x0
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression

Comment: Disable the exception breakpoint.  If it never crashes with an exception, it's a non-fatal exception, and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok thats what i am doing just thought if something i can fix to avid this as it may be one of the reason for app stuck at launch other then some delayed API process i need to do for app quick launch.

Comment: Also having this same issue. Hoping to find a solution other than disabling the breakpoint (this is just ignoring the problem imo).

Comment: I see this is native app issue where you doing something wrong,  I wasn't able to solve as its exception only at breakpoint no harm to the app.  There are other areas in my other app as well giving the same exception. Maybe just practice of designing views and models population of data is wrong somewhere on UI / background thread. Hope someone gets the answer.